# How to extract data without label from tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a tf dataset called train_ds:

```
directory = 'Data/dataset_train'

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  directory,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
    color_mode='grayscale',
  seed=123,
  image_size=(28, 28),
  batch_size=32)
```

This dataset is composed of 20000 images of "Fake" images and 20000 "Real" images and I want to extract X_train and y_train in numpy form from this tf dataset but I have only managed to get the labels out with

`y_train = np.concatenate([y for x, y in train_ds], axis=0)`

I also tried with this but it doesn't seem like it's iterating through the 20000 images:

```
for images, labels in train_ds.take(-1):  
    X_train = images.numpy()
    y_train = labels.numpy()
```

I really want to extract the images to X_train and the labels to y_train but I can't figure it out!
I apologize in advance for any mistake I've made and appreciate all the help I can get :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not apply further transformations to the dataset it will be a `BatchDataset`. You can create two lists to iterate over dataset. Here in total I have **2936** images.

```
x_train, y_train = [], []

for images, labels in train_ds:
  x_train.append(images.numpy())
  y_train.append(labels.numpy())

np.array(x_train).shape >> (92,)
```

It was generating batches. You can use `np.concatenate` to concat them.

```
x_train = np.concatenate(x_train, axis = 0) 
x_train.shape >> (2936,28,28,3)
```

Or you can unbatch the dataset and iterate over it:

```
for images, labels in train_ds.unbatch():
  x_train.append(images.numpy())
  y_train.append(labels.numpy())

x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_train.shape >> (2936,28,28,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TF Dataset method [unbatch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#unbatch)() to unbatch the dataset, then you can easily retrieve the data and the labels from it:

```
data=[]
for images, labels in ds.unbatch():
    data.append(images)
```